# Call the member function, although the object does not exist

Tags: c++, object, memory, member

In the code below, why can I call `printAlternativ` but not `print`?
To my understanding, the object should be removed and neither should work.

```
using namespace std;

class MemTest
{
public:
    MemTest(string);
    ~MemTest();
    void print();
    void printAlternative();
    string name;
};

void MemTest::print() {
    cout << "Print: " << name << "\n";
}

void MemTest::printAlternative() {
    cout << "Print Alternative\n";
}

MemTest::MemTest(string n) {
    cout << "Constructor\n";
    name = n;
}

MemTest::~MemTest() {
    cout << "Destructor\n";
}

void call(MemTest *b) {
    MemTest a("TestName");
    a.print();
    b = &a;
}

int main()
{
    MemTest *b = NULL;
    call(b);
    b->print(); // This crashes
    // b->printAlternative(); This works

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Undefined Behavior Land.  The only rule is there is no rules.

Comment: Ever heard of `new` operator

Comment: Short answer - because `printAlternativ` doesn't access any members of the class, so an instance isn't _technically_ needed. But that's not guaranteed to work.

Comment: The `call` function has no effect on the variable `b` in `main` – that `b` is always the null pointer.

Comment: @Sniper Yes, but that was not my question. I just take it as undefined behaviour, as I have not found any other explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After call() object get destructed, so now object b does not have any reference of any object and you are trying to access "name" data member of object because of that it get crashed.
You can verify it by adding a cout<<"Test line"; after call(b); line in main()

And why other one is working because member functions are associated with class and get assigned when first time we declare object and compiler only swipe data member in destructor()

Comment: Can I rely on this behaviour, because it seems you are suggesting that this is behaviour is by design. Do you have any proof of that, because I have not found any.

Comment: As we know that function get initialized in memory only once and works for every object only stack changes on every call for data. Because of that destructor does not swipe function.